# Creating a latex table from coeftest object in R

Tags: r, latex

I have `coeftest` class object that I coded for some purposes that `lm` class cannot achieve, but I need to export the object in the way as `xtable`(`lm`) does. Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think this could help you out:

```
library(AER) # I think coeftest() belongs to this package.
library(Hmisc)
latex(coeftest(model), digits=5)
```

Where `model` is the linear model estimated by `lm()`. `latex()` is a function from `Hmisc` package which is more general than `xtable`.

If this is not what you are looking for, then provide some data and the expected result so that we can figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model, se=coeftest(model), report=vcs)
```

model is the linear model. stargazer is, at least in my experience, more general than latex() from Hmisc.

Comment: I guess you the quotes are missing for the last argument:  report="vcs"

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to use xtable, could write down a small function:

```
library(lmtest)
library(xtable)

xtable.coeftest <- function (x, caption = NULL, label = NULL, align =     NULL, digits = NULL, 
                         display = NULL, ...) 
{
  class(x) <- "matrix"
  li<-list(coef=x)
  return(xtable:::xtable.summary.lm(li, caption = caption, label = label, 
                                align = align, digits = digits, display = display))
}


example(coeftest)
xtable(coeftest(fm))
```

It is admittedly not the most elegant (there are two issues, one that it is difficult to convert a `coeftest` object, second that `xtable.summary.lm` uses `x$coef` instead of `coef(x)`) but it works!